# Serving static files stored in the physical machine using docker-compose

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose` file that I'm using to host a backend service:

```
nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - /projects/tour/tour-nginx-conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - /projects/tour/tour-nginx-conf/tour.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/tour.online.conf
      - /projects/tour/tour-nginx-conf/security.conf:/etc/nginx/nginxconfig.io/security.conf
      - /projects/tour/tour-nginx-conf/proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/nginxconfig.io/proxy.conf
      - /projects/tour/tour-nginx-conf/general.conf:/etc/nginx/nginxconfig.io/general.conf

tour-be:
    image: tour-be
    container_name: tour-be
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - be_data:/uploads
```

The nginx conf file:

```
...
location = /api {
    return 302 /api/;
}

location = /bo {
    return 302 /bo/;
}

location /api/ {
    proxy_pass http://tour-be:5000/;
}

location /uploads {
    root /uploads/;
}
...
```

I'm storing some static files under the `/uploads/image` directory. As of now I'm not able to get these images and I get the standard Nginx error 404 page. I get that this way I'm looking for the container filesystem path. How should I use correctly the volumes as declared in the `docker-compose.yaml` file?

Comment: Check my comment under the @Besworks answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't given the `nginx` container access to the uploads directory. You just need to copy the volume entry from the `tour-be` container. Both containers can share access to the same directory.

```
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - /projects/tour/tour-nginx-conf/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
      - /projects/tour/tour-nginx-conf/tour.conf:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/tour.online.conf
      - /projects/tour/tour-nginx-conf/security.conf:/etc/nginx/nginxconfig.io/security.conf
      - /projects/tour/tour-nginx-conf/proxy.conf:/etc/nginx/nginxconfig.io/proxy.conf
      - /projects/tour/tour-nginx-conf/general.conf:/etc/nginx/nginxconfig.io/general.conf
      - be_data:/uploads
      
  tour-be:
    image: tour-be
    container_name: tour-be
    depends_on:
      mysql:
        condition: service_healthy
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - be_data:/uploads
```

Then make sure your `nginx.conf` has the following configuration :

```
http {
  server {
    port_in_redirect off;
    location /uploads/ {
      alias /uploads/;
    }
  }
}
```

The `port_in_redirect off;` directive is extremely important. Without it, nginx will strip the externally mapped port number from your request and try to redirect to port 80.

Comment: Besides that, if the files will be available as `/uploads/filename` from the container filesystem hierarchy, and should be available under the `scheme://example.com/uploads/filename` URLs, the `root /uploads/;` directive inside the `location /uploads/ { ... }` should be changed to `root "";` (yes, it looks somewhat weird, I know). The other choice is to use `alias /uploads/;` instead.

Comment: Yes, that's a very good point, I had not noticed that issue. The way the config is written in the question would be trying to serve an `uploads/` subdirectory from within the `/uploads/` root directory. Using `alias` would be the most semantic approach.

Comment: thank you both, I'm following you suggestions, what else could be wrong if I still get 404?

Comment: Maybe because the volume declaration is bad, try `./be_data:/uploads` instead. Though I would expect that the container simply wouldn't start in that case. Perhaps there is some other issue in your nginx.conf. Have you checked your docker logs? Try `docker-compose up` without the `-d` flag to watch the logs as the container starts.

Comment: After some extensive testing, I found the issue: nginx is stripping the port number when redirecting to the alias. I've updated my answer with a section about this.

Comment: I made it work. I followed you suggestions about volume listed in both nginx and tour_be containers. However the volume declaration made that way was wrong. To make it work I changed be_data:/uploads to /uploads:/uploads. The first /uploads is the directory in my host machine where I'm saving images. Instead of a volume I'm pointing to a directory. Is it conceptually right? I also used the alias as Ivan suggested

Comment: Moreover in my specif case I didn't need port_in_redirect off;
I tried my nginx configuration with and without that line and after changing the volume as I mentioned in the previous comment I'm able to retrieve the image from the directory hosted in the machine always

Comment: It's fine to use a local directory for your volume. I do it all the time. Generally I use a `./relative` path in the project directory rather than an absolute one from the root of my host system.